# Python Wordsearch: How do I print out the word found and convert the other letters into an exclamation mark?

Tags: python

With a test file like this:

```
hfhfdhjkayuwe
cmnzgdsoifoid
skjhfbskjfhkhsdj
smjbfjkshfsjfhk
sjhfhsfkjhsfkjlfjsl
qwuaoirhdfbjkak
kjfaheuiwopfakjh
sweetfoodislife
kjhfsiuskjhlawrpof
sfkjzaljifopwesdhj
```

How do I fix my code so it searches for words diagonally, horizontally, vertically, from right and left, from front and back, and when it finds a word a user inputs, it prints out the grid, showing where that word is found and converting every other character into an exclamation mark? For example, with the test file above, if the user inputs "sweetfoodislife", I want my code to output the following:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Sweetfoodislife
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

I simply want to know how to convert every letter into an exclamation mark except the word found which the user inputs. If the word is not found, the output should produce "I can't find this word."

I have the following code, but it produces an error on line 12, saying list index out of range.

```
def grid():
    filename = input(“Enter name of test file:”)
    word = input("What word are you searching: ")
    file = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
    with open(filename, 'w') as file_2:
        for item in file:
           print("!", item) 
    a = len(word)
    b = len(word[0])
    for i in range(a):
        for j in range(b):
            if file[0] == word[i][j]:
                if word in file[i][j]:
                    print(open(filename).read())
    print("I can’t find this word")
```

grid()

Comment: You seem to be mixing up your variables `word` and `file`. `len(word[0])` and `word[i][j]` don't make sense because `word` is simply a string. Can you explain what you are trying to implement - how you want your code to solve the problem?

Comment: @Stuart, I’m trying to make the code look at the letters in the word the user inputs starting from the first letter, then search through the grid to see if it finds the word anywhere. If it finds it, it should print the entire grid, converting everything else to exclamation marks while printing the word where it is found on the grid. If the word does not exist anywhere on the grid, it should print “I cannot find this word”

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
txt='''\
hfhfdhjkayuwe
cmnzgdsoifoid
skjhfbskjfhkhsdj
smjbfjkshfsjfhk
sjhfhsfkjhsfkjlfjsl
qwuaoirhdfbjkak
kjfaheuiwopfakjh
sweetfoodislife
kjhfsiuskjhlawrpof
sfkjzaljifopwesdhj'''

tgt='sweetfoodislife'
```

You can do:

```
print('\n'.join([line if line==tgt else '!'*len(line)  for line in txt.splitlines()]))
```

Prints:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
sweetfoodislife
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: thanks for your input. Please, see below each comment, I couldn't put everything into one single comment.
I want tgt to be any word that the user inputs, so I have a prompt for the user to input any word. Then the output should reveal where the word is and convert the others to exclamation mark, or if the word is not found, the output should print "I can't find this word".

Comment: So, I modified your code this way: Tgt = input(“Enter word”) file = open(filename, 'r').readlines() #this opens the text file that contains the grid if tgt[0] in file: print('\n'.join([line if line == word else '.'*len(line) for line in txt.splitlines()])) #here I’m trying to make it print whatever word the user inputs, and make the others exclamation marks. else: print(“I can’t find this word”)

Comment: So for example, if the user inputs “mily” with the same text file in my original post, I want the output to be seeing where mily is found: !!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! mily!!!!!!!!!!!!!! And I want this search to be from every angle: diagonal, hori, vertical, from right, left, from back. In your code that I modified above, it keeps telling me that “I can’t find this word” for any word the user inputs.